# Add autoplay functionality to pure CSS slider

Tags: html, css, slider, slideshow

I would like to add an autoplay functionality to my css slider but not sure if it is possible with the current code structure. Any suggestions as to how to add without modifying the current code structure too much?

I have created a fiddle for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh0a3ypk/

```
    <div class="wav-gal-splash-container">
    <div class="wav-gal-splash-slide-container"> 
    <input id="wav-gal-splash-slider-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-selector1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="wav-gal-splash-slider-1" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-label-1"></label>     
    <input id="wav-gal-splash-slider-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-selector2" />
    <label for="wav-gal-splash-slider-2" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-label-2"></label>       
    <input id="wav-gal-splash-slider-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-selector3" />
    <label for="wav-gal-splash-slider-3" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-label-3"></label>     
    <input id="wav-gal-splash-slider-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-selector4" />
    <label for="wav-gal-splash-slider-4" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-label-4"></label>       
    <input id="wav-gal-splash-slider-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-selector5" />
    <label for="wav-gal-splash-slider-5" class="wav-gal-splash-slider-label-5"></label>      
    <div class="wav-gal-splash-slider-background">
    <ul class="wav-gal-splash-slides">
    <li><a href=""><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=one" /></a></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=two" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=three" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=four" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=five" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I hope this would help : http://snipplr.com/view/64057/simple-autoslide/

Comment: You should use CSS animation, instead of transition... Animation allows repeating...